# Delete id from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I have a several users, when I want to delete an user I use the following code:

```
<td><b><a href='.?control=directeur&action=verwijderGebruiker&id=".$leerling->getId()."'><img src='img/delete.png' /></a></b></td>
```

In my controller:

```
 private function verwijderAction()
 {
       $this->model->verwijderGebruiker();
       $this->forward('default','directeur');
 }
```

And in my model:

```
 public function verwijderGebruiker()
 {
   $id = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

   if($id!=false)
   {
     $sql = 'DELETE FROM `contacten` WHERE `id`=:id';
     $stmnt = $this->db->prepare($sql); // bereid de query voor
     $stmnt->bindParam(':id',$id); // bindParam = verbindt de parameter: ":<parameter>" met de "<variable>".
     $stmnt->execute(); // voert de query uit
   } 
}
```

When I want to delete an ID it says the right thing in the URL `(action=verwijderGebruiker&id=5)` but it doesn't delete it, instead it goes back to the home page.

Comment: there is no logic to forward back to homepage. Is there any code missing?

Comment: change sql query  like `$sql = 'DELETE FROM contacten WHERE id=:id';` and check please.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh it still doesn't delete it

Comment: I don't know what kind of framework you are using, but shouldn't `action=verwijderGebruiker` be `action=verwijderAction` as that is the name of your controller?

Comment: @Blank "*Raptor: Is there any code missing?*"

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Raptor that's my point... and no there's no code missing from my own code

Comment: Also check if your framework is not emptying the global `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST`, etc. variables.

Answer (score 0):

your `id` never gets inside your method. you have to hand it over to your function as a parameter:

```
public function verwijderGebruiker($id)
{
   $id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
   // ....
}

//call it outside your class with your request-variable:
$my_class = new MyClass();
$my_class->verwijderGebruiker($_REQUEST['id']);
```

Comment: it still doesnt work and i have no idea why it doesnt

Comment: @Blank  please show me the code where your class gets instanced and your method(s) get called!

Answer (score 0):

Although you should check the value in $id before testing if it != false there are more fundamental issues: changing database values based on parameters you get from a URL could allow someone to keep trying different values on the url, and thereby change database values.

You may be removing records silently, or you may be doing nothing, depending on the value plugged into your URL by $leerling->getId()

I think $id probably has no value in it.  The test is probably silently failing to say anything as it evaluates to false and no DB update can follow.

More importantly: the $id must be sent in a POST, not a GET request.

See: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#/Request_methods

> using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect.

Otherwise the URL can be sent with lots of sequential IDs and records changed in your database, nightmare security fail!

Additionally, your test not only needs to ensure $id has a value, but that it is a DB record that can be deleted and to return a result, catching any faults.